# document.getElementById is null for login screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I've recently started learning Javascript and I am trying to create a login system prototype. The aim is that the user inputs the required details (the username being 'Mike' and password 'password') and then gets redirected to a new webpage. However, no redirection happens. This is due to me getting a document.getElementById(...) is null error.

Most answers I have found say that the document isn't fully loaded by the time javascript is executed. However, due to the code not executing until a button is pressed, I believe it is not this issue.

My HTML code is:

```
<form id="form_id" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="Username" class="login_textbox"/><br><br>
     <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="Password" class="login_textbox"/><br>

     <br><input type="button" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="validate()" class="login_button" /> 
  </form>
```

My javascript code is:

```
function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    if ( username == "Mike" && password == "password"){
       alert ("Login Successful");
       window.location = "Pages/homepage.htm";
       return false;
       }
```

}

Comment: there should be a `"` after `id="password`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing end quote at the ID password field.

```html
id="password value="Password"
```

```html
id="password value="Password"
```

I suggest you to use some editor with syntax highlighter, and also better maintain structure of your documents & code. Also, you may try w3c markup validators.

All of this will help you avoid such mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your HTML code, you have forgot a " at the end of the `id` attribute the `password` field. Fix it like this:

```
<form id="form_id" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="Username" class="login_textbox"/><br><br>
 <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="Password" class="login_textbox"/><br>

 <br><input type="button" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="validate()" class="login_button" />
```